# Why do I keep getting this error at runtime? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am attempting to use the "Hashmap" implementation for the code below. I simply want to get an element from the map and print it out to the console in eclipse. Unfortunately I keep getting this error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException) printed onto the console. I don't know what I am doing wrong but I've tried allot of workarounds but I keep getting this error. Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Here is my code:

```
package repo;

import java.util.*;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

 public class ConsoleDisplayData {

// Fields
static DateTime currentTime = new DateTime();
static Map<Integer, String> smtpSuccess = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
public static String step0;

public static void storeSuccessData()
{
    // Store Elements in Map
    smtpSuccess.put(0, "Initiating..");
    smtpSuccess.put(1, "\nS: 220 smtp.localhost.com ESMTP Postfix");
    smtpSuccess.put(2, "\nC: HELO relay.localhost.com");
    smtpSuccess.put(3, "\nS: 250 Hello relay.localhost.com, I am glad to meet you");
    smtpSuccess.put(4, "\nC: MAIL FROM:" + "<"  + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfSenderEmail.getText() +  ">" );
    smtpSuccess.put(5, "\nC: RCPT TO: " + "<" + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfRecepientEmail.getText()  + ">" );
    smtpSuccess.put(6, "\nS: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>");
    smtpSuccess.put(7, "\nC: From: " + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfSenderName.getText() + "<" + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfSenderEmail.getText()  +">");
    smtpSuccess.put(8, "\nC: To: Recepient Name" + "<" + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfRecepientEmail.getText()  +">");
    smtpSuccess.put(9, "\nC: Date: " + currentTime );
    smtpSuccess.put(10, "\nC: Subject: " + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jlSubject.getText());
    smtpSuccess.put(11, "\nC: " +  presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtaBody.getText());
    smtpSuccess.put(12, "\nS: 221 End");


    // Print Step 0
    step0 = smtpSuccess.get(0);
    System.out.println(step0);

}   

public static void main(String [] args)
{
      // Run    
      storeSuccessData();
}
```

Comment: at which line you are getting the error?

Comment: Where does the NPE get thrown?

Comment: Could you post the full error message?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at repo.ConsoleDisplayData.storeSuccessData(ConsoleDisplayData.java:18)
 at repo.ConsoleDisplayData.main(ConsoleDisplayData.java:37)

Comment: @BabatundeOmodayo and line number 18 is ??

Comment: So line 18, which one is it in your post?

Comment: what is presentation ? - does it got initialized ?

Comment: Try putting `smtpSuccess = new HashMap<Integer, String>();` inside the static method.

Comment: check this line smtpSuccess.put(4, "\nC: MAIL FROM:" + "<"  + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfSenderEmail.getText() +  ">" );

Comment: LINE 18: smtpSuccess.put(1, "\nS: 220 smtp.localhost.com ESMTP Postfix");

Comment: @tobias_k i have tried doing that but it is still giving me this error

Comment: A NPE at that line does not make sense. Are you sure that that line still corresponds to the code in your question? Did you insert or remove anything?

Comment: @mani that isn't really the issue, as I have already tried commenting all the elements the have references to other packages and classes.

Comment: @tobias_k that wouldn't make a difference since the static block is executed when the class is loaded (prior to method execution). @Babatunde are you sure you didn't mess with the lines or did post all code? There shouldn't be an NPE at `smtpSuccess.put(1, ...)` unless the code is incomplete.

Comment: @user902383 presentation is a separate package that I am trying to reference from this class but even when comment out external references in the map, it still shows me the error

Comment: @tobias_k the code is complete. i put everything into one class and I wanted to test to see if the map was actually working

Comment: check is `presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfRecepientEmail` is null

Comment: @BabatundeOmodayo you still seem to have posted different code since when I count the lines in your post, line 18 is this (which still wouldn't explain the NPE): `smtpSuccess.put(2, "\nC: HELO relay.localhost.com");`

Comment: @user902383 it is null because it is supposed to collect information from the user on the SMTPMailCientGui, however I am only trying to see if the Map works.

Comment: So here we have the problem: calling `getText()` on a _null_ reference will cause ... you guessed right ... a _NullPointerException_.

Comment: @BabatundeOmodayo and as it is null, you cant call method on it,otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Thomas i will remove these elements and test the map again.

Comment: @user902383 thanks for your help, I'll implement the map again.

Answer (score 2):

I assume line 18 is this one (or one of the next):

```
smtpSuccess.put(4, "\nC: MAIL FROM:" + "<"  + presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfSenderEmail.getText() +  ">" );
```

Any of those could be null, so please check (ideally using a debugger):

- presentation
- presentation.SMTPMailClientGui
- presentation.SMTPMailClientGui.jtfSenderEmail

**UPDATE**

Since `presentation` seems to be a package I assume `SMTPMailClientGui` is a class and `jtfSenderEmail` is a static field. In that context `jtfSenderEmail` seems to be null (unless that's not the correct line).

Comment: Line 18 is smtpSuccess.put(1, "\nS: 220 smtp.localhost.com ESMTP Postfix");

Comment: @BabatundeOmodayo that doesn't make sense if you _really_ posted the complete code. In that case the only thing that could be null would be `smtpSuccess` which in turn should have triggered the NPE at line 17 already.

Comment: The error is point to ->>>> smtpSuccess.put(1, "\nS: 220 smtp.localhost.com ESMTP Postfix"); so it has nothing to do with the external references.

Comment: @BabatundeOmodayo please read my comments above, if you posted the complete code as-is, line 18 seems to be the next line. If by any chance you compiled without the 2 comments line 18 would be the line I pointed at. In any case, the best you can do is start a debugger and check line by line.